# What flavor of underlying EVM is Substrate Frontier using (the EVM-compatible client)?

Tags: smartcontracts, substrate, parity, polkadot, evm

I was able to successfully build my own Ethereum-compatible Substrate by basically following the [Substrate Dev Frontier Workshop](https://substrate.dev/frontier-workshop/#/) tutorial ( which uses SputnikVM as the underlying EVM engine, as per the Frontier [Evm Documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/master/docs/frame/evm.md) ).

I am aware of the fact that Ethereum is behaving more or less differently after each for, like for example, a decrease or increase of Gas costs of various EVM OPCODEs after some forks.

That being said, what kind of Ethereum is this Sputnik-based client exactly? Is this client similar to *Berlin*, *Istanbul* or similar to something older like *Homestead* or *Byzantium*? Should I use the latest solc compiler like `0.8.6+commit.11564f7e` or should I use something older like `0.6.0+commit.26b70077` or `0.4.0+commit.acd334c9` ?

I would like to know because I need to document exactly what the gas cost of every contract deployment or method call or, prevent incompatibility.

Comment: I'd assumed it was tracking whatever ethereum is currently doing (possibly with a slight lag) so maybe any london adjustments are not yet baked in. It's a good question!

Answer (score 0):

The Sputnik evm implementation contains different flavors of EvmConfig for you to choose from.

If you look into the [source code](https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm/blob/0fbde9fa7797308290f89111c6abe5cee55a5eac/runtime/src/lib.rs), you will find four of them:

```
impl Config {
    /// Frontier hard fork configuration.
    pub const fn frontier() -> Config { ... }

    /// Istanbul hard fork configuration.
    pub const fn istanbul() -> Config { ... }

    /// Berlin hard fork configuration.
    pub const fn berlin() -> Config { ... }

    /// london hard fork configuration.
    pub const fn london() -> Config { ... }
}
```

According to frontier's pallet-evm documentation

> The gas configurations are configurable. Right now, a pre-defined London hard fork configuration option is provided.

Thus currently they are using the london hard fork configuration, which is confirmed by [this commit](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/commit/6df6b1da57b1f61a62c040a40bec46d76d3183ee), which shows they switched the default config from istanbul to london:

```
...
        /// EVM config used in the module.
        fn config() -> &'static EvmConfig {
-           &ISTANBUL_CONFIG
+           &LONDON_CONFIG
        }
    }

@@ -571,7 +571,7 @@ impl GasWeightMapping for () {
    }
}

-static ISTANBUL_CONFIG: EvmConfig = EvmConfig::istanbul();
+static LONDON_CONFIG: EvmConfig = EvmConfig::london();
...
```

If you want detailed parameters of each hard fork, be sure to check [here](https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm/blob/0fbde9fa7797308290f89111c6abe5cee55a5eac/runtime/src/lib.rs)